# Facebook app not retrieving user info

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I just built an app with the Facebook PHP SDK and set it up. I am testing it and though I get the image to show up from my profile, the user info requested is not showing up. Here is the screenshot of the results
[image: screenshot of the result]

Here is the php code that I uploaded to the server. Note that the App ID and Secret have been removed from here.

```
<?php

require ('src/facebook.php');

$app_id = " "; //has been removed
$secret = " "; //has been removed
$app_url = "http://apps.facebook.com/instahomework/";

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret). 
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $app_id,
  'secret' =>  $secret,
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(); 
}
// This call will always work since we are fetching public data.
$naitik = $facebook->api('/naitik');

?>
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
    <title>php-sdk example 1 - user login and authorisation</title>
    <style>
        body { font-family: Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; }
        a { text-decoration:none; }
        a:hover { text-decoration:underline; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<pre>
<?php print_r($_REQUEST); ?>
</pre>
    <?php if ($user) { ?>
        <h2>Welcome</h2>
        <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture"><br/>
        <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></a><br/>
        <br/>
        Gender : <?php echo $gender; ?><br/>
        Locale : <?php echo $locale; ?><br/>
        Username : <?php echo $username; ?><br/>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <strong><em>You have not granted this App permission to access your data. Redirecting to permissions request...</em></strong>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i don't see the code where you are setting `$gender`, `$locale` and `$username`. Where is it?

Comment: @RaulPinto it is on line 63 - 65 before the </body> tag. Thanks

Comment: That is not, what `<?php print_r($_REQUEST); ?>` is doing. Check Owens answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should replace your HTML code with:

```
    <h2>Welcome</h2>
    <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture"><br/>
    <a href="<?php echo $user_profile['link']; ?>"><?php echo $user_profile['name']; ?></a><br/>
    <br/>
    Gender : <?php echo $user_profile['gender']; ?><br/>
    Locale : <?php echo $user_profile['locale']; ?><br/>
    Username : <?php echo $user_profile['username']; ?><br/>
```

as the "user info" you want is requested by this line of code:

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
```

and stored into the `$user_profile` array.

Another workaround (but not recommended) is using [`extract()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) to extract the data from facebook into your global variable scope, by adding this line of code:

```
extract($user_profile);
```

Comment: Ok thank you, that worked. I would upvote but it will not let me because reputation less than 15 :/

Comment: @JGallardo - Check the answer as correct and your reputation will increase.